# Multimeter functionality for raspberry pi

Tags: sensor, analog-to-digital

Are there any sensors that would allow me to measure voltage/current/resistance similar to using a multimeter but would allow me to interface with them through a library? (for example, measuring village from a solar cell and plot it on a graph through python)
I've heard about ADC expanders, do they work on voltages and if so what range? (I need up to about 10-20V) What kind of precision can you get? And are there similar sensors for current and resistance?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: An ADC is the obvious choice.  They measure voltage against a reference voltage.  If you are measuring current or resistance you'd have to build a circuit which converted the answer to a voltage.  You can read ADCs in all sorts of ways.  Probably best if you firm up on what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what you want to do. It is relatively easy to measure small (~1V) +ve voltages **RELATIVE TO THE PI GROUND**. Any ADC can do this, depending on the precision required. Higher voltages can be measured with appropriate voltage dividers (which is what multimeters do internally).
I have done this with `MCP3002` ADC and also using the analog inputs of an `ATMEGA`. If you go the latter either an `Arduino` or `Gertboard` may be an easier solution.

Measuring -ve voltages requires additional circuitry, and a -ve supply voltage.

Floating measurements (voltage or resistance) are harder, and you would be better to go for an external data logger module, with its own supply, which can float WRT the Pi, and use a serial protocol to log the data.